# C/C++ - Run system("process &") and then write to its stdin

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, stdin

I am working on Linux and C/C++. I wrote a program with some threads (#include pthread.h) and I run it with sudo.

One thread runs a process (mplayer) and leaves it running by adding " &", so that system() can return quickly.

```
system("mplayer -loop 0 /mnt/usb/* &");
```

The mplayer process runs normally and plays music as expected.

After that, I get its process ID by running pidof. Let's say that it returns 2449. A posix mutex is used to write/read that process ID on this thread and on the second thread.

On the second thread I try to write data to mplayer by using the /proc/2449/fd/0 pipe (is it called a pipe or stream?):

```
system("echo \">\" > /proc/2499/fd/0");
```

system() returns 0, but the mplayer process does not get anything. The ">" command should play the next track.

Is the stdin stream being inherited by some other process?

There are several fd's listed under the 2449 process, is one of them (besides 0) the stdin stream?

```
root@pisanlink:/proc# cd 2499
root@pisanlink:/proc/2499# cd fd
root@pisanlink:/proc/2499/fd# ls
0  1  2  3  4  5  7
root@pisanlink:/proc/2499/fd#
```

I also tried another approach... I used popen() with write permissions. I tried sending the command with fprintf, but mplayer didn't seem to receive anything as well.

If any more code is needed, please let me know.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `man 3 popen` might be a better match for your overall goals.  Using system() on `echo` seems particularly roundabout.

Comment: With `popen`, you need to either set the `FILE` in line-buffered or unbuffered mode (see: `setvbuf`) or `fflush` after you print a command to it.

Comment: You might look up mplayer's -slave option, then keep on with sending commands via the FILE returned from popen.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Yeah, I shouldn't program as if I was using a shell, but I'm just starting with this.

Comment: By the way, could someone tell me why there are so many opened fd's under the process? 0  1  2  3  4  5  7

Comment: @sjnarv: I will look up that. I didn't know there was a cleaner way to control mplayer.

Comment: @R.. I will use your suggestion if the other 2 don't work. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the mplayer slave option and the input as a fifo file. It is working correctly.

Create the Linux fifo file with mkfifo:

```
system("mkfifo /tmp/slpiplay_fifo");
```

Open mplayer with:

```
system("mplayer -slave -idle -really-quiet -input file=/tmp/slpiplay_fifo /mnt/usb_slpiplay/* &");
```

Pass a "next" command to mplayer by using the fifo:

```
system("echo \"pt_step 1\" >> /tmp/slpiplay_fifo");
```

Comment: Using the named unix pipe is a good solution. But don't use `system` to write to a file. Just use `FILE*f =fopen("/tmp/slpiplay_fifo","w"); fprintf(f,"pt_step 1\n"); fclose(f);`. The cost of spawning a process is about 1000 more expensive than just calling a system call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MarkLakata . It just seemed faster to type system than writing to the file. I will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (not system) to open the process.  It will create the process with a pipe that you can either read from or write to (but not both).  In your case, you'd open it with "w" for writing.  From there you can simply use `fwrite` to send data to the process' stdin.

Pseudo-code Example:

```
FILE * pFile = popen("mplayer -loop 0 /mnt/usb/*", "w");

if(pFile == NULL)
   // Handle error

// Send ">" to process' stdin
const char * psData = ">";
const size_t nDataLen = strlen(psData);
size_t nNumWritten = fwrite(psData, 1, nDataLen, pFile);

if(nNumWritten != nDataLen)
   // Handle error

...

pclose(pFile);
pFile = NULL;
```