# C++. How to call commands of a program that waits for standard input after start?

Tags: c++

I want to make a wrapper around `stockfish` (chess engine) that uses `UCI` (Universal chess interface). Running stockfish from the terminal will open its shell:

```
Stockfish 8 64 by T. Romstad, M. Costalba, J. Kiiski, G. Linscott
|
```

(where I - cursor)
it waits input commands (like `go`, `position`, `setoption`, etc...)
I need to read output of e.g. `go` command.
It is the same if i wanted to receive `select * from *` connecting to database with `mysql`, `psql` or another DBMS executable or to read some output from python command using `python` executable
I'm using linux, but crossplatform solutions are more preferable

I tried to make a program using `popen` and `fscanf` in while loop but i guess i need something non-blocking current thread while waiting output from stdout

Comment: You can have your program create a pseudo-tty device on Linux, attach it to `stockfish`'s standard input and output, and be able to control it that way. `stockfish` thinks it's running in a terminal, but it's input and output comes from your program. This is a fairly advanced topic, that cannot really be explained in a brief paragraph or two on stackoverflow. You have a lot of reading and learning to do, if you want to implement something like that. This has nothing really to do with C++.

Comment: @samVarshavchik thanks for the reply, i thought it is pretty common task in c++ programming

Comment: If you would like a portable solution, I would recommend python's subprocess module. You can create another process and communicate with it by subrpocess' functions. It's still a lot to learn, but you may start with this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542960/run-interactive-bash-with-popen-and-a-dedicated-tty-python

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485923/launch-an-exe-process-with-stdin-stdout-and-stderr

Comment: Search is your friend:

Comment: [Sending data to stdin of another process through linux terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37424497/9199167)

Comment: [C/C++ - Run system(“process &”) and then write to its stdin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430942/c-c-run-systemprocess-and-then-write-to-its-stdin)

Comment: [Redirect stdout of two processes to another process's stdin in Linux C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041416/redirect-stdout-of-two-processes-to-another-processs-stdin-in-linux-c)

Comment: [Read another process' stdout in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093252/read-another-process-stdout-in-c)

Comment: [How do i run a program from another program and pass data to it via stdin in c or c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231188/how-do-i-run-a-program-from-another-program-and-pass-data-to-it-via-stdin-in-c-o)